# How to get the index of v-for in a function in vue js html?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component

If the status is true, i need to splice that array from the fields in html vue js

I need to pass the index value to a function.
How can it be possible.

My error is

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: index is not defined
    at Object.success (80155f2d-c534-4b8f-ba5f-20edef1496ab:1032)
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

My html code is

```
<div class="card-content" v-for="(arrest, index) in arestee" :key="index">
  --my data--
 <a @click="deleteSubmit(arrest)" target="_blank">Delete Arestee</a></button>

 </div>
```

On clicking deleteSubmit of arrest, I am passing the data to a function

My vue js code is

```
 deleteSubmit: function(arrest) {
                                    var vm = this;
                                    data = {};
                                    data['docId'] = this.id;

                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: 'http://localhost:4000/doc/remove/',
                                        data: data,
                                        type: "POST",
                                        dataType: 'json',
                                        success: function(arrest) {
                                            if (arrest.status)
                                            {

                                                alert("Success")
                                                arrest.splice(index, 1);

                                            }
                                            else {
                                                alert("Failed")


                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                    return false;
                                },



arrest.splice(index, 1);
```

I need to pass the index value to this

Comment: just passs the index also , the same way you are passing arrest. Like this : `deleteSubmit(arrest, index)`

Comment: if so, how to update the function?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will have to pass index to deleteSubmit, as Vamsi Krishna commented

```
 <a @click="deleteSubmit(arrest, index)" target="_blank">Delete Arestee</a></button>
```

Then you can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the index in the callback:

```
deleteSubmit: function(arrest, index) {
  ...
  success: function(index, arrest) {
    if (arrest.status){
      alert("Success")
      arrest.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      alert("Failed")
    }
  }.bind(null, index)
  ...
}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: arrest.splice is not a function
    at 80155f2d-c534-4b8f-ba5f-20edef1496ab:1031
    at i (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)

Comment: this is probably an error in your `arrest.splice`, check with `console.log(index, arrest)`, and check if the values are passed and hold the correct values in your success callback.

Comment: yes console.log(index, arrest) has values correctly

Comment: it seems like `arrest` is not of type array?

Comment: inside if(arrest.status), if i type console.log(arrest,index) index is correct but arrest is status:true

Comment: i think it causes the problem.. how can i correct it

Comment: I created a stackoverflow chat for that, since the question is answered and any more comments are off topic. Here is the [Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172609/question-how-to-get-the-index-of-v-for-in-a-function-in-vue-js-html)